# How do you shift items in a doubly linked list starting from a certain position?

Tags: list

I was just fiddling around with doubly linked lists and I was going over how to shift all items one to the right. I was wondering how you make it so that I could shift all items starting at (lets say) position 2 up to 10 to the right by one space instead of all items.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using careful splicing of your doubly linked list.  Here is a diagram showing where you start:

```
1 <-> 2 <-> 3 <-> ... <-> 9 <-> 10 <-> 11 <-> 12 <-> ...
^ head                           ^ p
```

And here is what you want to achieve:

```
1 <-> 11 <-> 2 <-> 3 ... <-> 10 <-> 12 <-> ...
```

Pseudocode:

```
Node start = head.next;
Node end = p.next.next;
// connect 1 node to 11 node, in both directions
head.next = p.next;
p.next.prev = head;
// connect 11 node to 2 node, in both directions
head.next.next = start;
start.prev = head.next;
// connect 10 node to 12 node, in both directions
p.next = end;
end.prev = p;
```